# Group by and with by clauses may not contain aggregate functions

Tags: sql

Not sure what is going on here.... I know it's something to do with the max and group by statements... Any help greatly appreciated!

```
         select 
          c_clm as ClaimNo,
          i_pol as Policy,
          d_rcv_clm as Received,
          c_sta_clm as Status,
          d_tmn_clm as Terminated,
          c_tmn_clm as Reason,
          MAX(pym.d_rls_pym)  as Payment,
          c_sgm as Segment


          from ltc_p.VLTC_CLM_WK clm

            left join pearl_p.TLTC915_PYM pym  on
            clm.i_sys_clm = pym.i_sys_clm

             where c_sgm = 'am'

              group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your seventh column is:

```
MAX(pym.d_rls_pym)
```

You can't group by this.  Change your group by clause to:

```
group by c_clm, i_pol, d_rcv_clm, c_sta_clm, d_tmn_clm, c_tmn_clm, c_sgm
```

I changed the numbers to column names, since most databases do not support reference numbers in group bys.  You can do the same thing as:

```
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops

group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,8

Fixed it.